# How to select the values for n0 when proving Big Oh - Which is the correct method?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis, asymptotic-complexity

Consider the question,

Prove *f(n) = n<sup>2</sup> + 3 is O(n<sup>2</sup>).*

I understand that we need to find two positive constants c and n<sub>0</sub> such that n>=n<sub>0</sub> and f(n)<=c*g(n).

So it would be:

n<sup>2</sup>+3 <= c*g(n<sup>2</sup>) ............ {substuting g(n) = n<sup>2</sup>}

n<sup>2</sup>+3 <= c*n<sup>2</sup>.......{assume n<sub>0</sub> >=1 and substitute the value}

1+3 <= c*1..........{n<sup>2</sup>=1*1=1}

4<=c

Therefore I get the solution f(n) is O(n<sup>2</sup>) when C=4 and n<sub>0</sub>>=1

However, consider the following.

n<sup>2</sup>+3 <= c*n<sup>2</sup>.......{assume n<sub>0</sub> >=2 and substitute the value}

2<sup>2</sup>+3 <= c*2<sup>2</sup>

4+3 <= c*4

7 <= 4*c

if c = 2

7<=4*2.... satisfied for all n<sub>0</sub> >=2

This also proves that f(n) is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

**Which is the correct method and why?**

**How do I select the optimal values for c and n<sub>0</sub>?**

Note: I got this example from  [Proving and Disproving BigO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247978/proving-and-disproving-bigo?rq=1) which used yet another method of proof which I didn't understand.

Comment: @ user who down-voted, kindly explain why this post is down-voted as I consider this a legitimate question that improves understanding of algorithm analysis.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but big-O analysis probably fits better on [cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) rather than on SO, which is more focussed on practical programming problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is faulty. 
I think your question is Prove f(n) = n<sup>2</sup> + 3 is O(n<sup>2</sup>) and g(n) must be given as n<sup>2</sup> in the question itself. (You can't assume g(n) as n<sup>2</sup>).

How to choose c and n<sub>0</sub> :

Refer to this for example : http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~booth/311-01/notes/bigOex.html

Basically, you can choose c and n<sub>0</sub> which fit to your intuition. As you expect, there can be multiple possibilities for c and n<sub>0</sub>.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I edited the question to O( n2).

Also, if there are multiple possibilities for c and n0  shouldn't we try to find the most optimal one? Is there such a rule?

Comment: See, there is nothing like 'optimal c' or 'optimal n0'. Again, go back to the definition. What does it say? It says to just find if """"THERE EXIST"""" c and n0. We have to find one possibility of such c and n0 and that's it. We can be confident enough to say f(n) = O(g(n)). We need not worry if these are good values or not. For example if you find out that c=4 and n0=1 satisfy your problem, mention these two values and you are gonna get full marks. :). But keep in mind c and n0 must be positive